# Имплементация навигации по страницам

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт вытягивает из базы последние 10 постов (на главную). Внизу страницы должна быть навигация по страницам (<- next page и previous page ->). Как это лучше имплементировать на php? Передавать через гет диапазон дат старых постов и вытягивать их из базы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: при клике на "<- next page и previous page ->" просто редиректил на эту же самую страницу, но уже с GET-параметром, например:

```
  header("Location: http://example.com/search?page=N");
```

Где N-порядковый номер страницы с 10 постами. Далее я выполнял бы SQL запрос в роде этого:

```
 SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date_add DESC LIMIT N*10, 10
```

Ну, а далее уже дело техники.

Comment: а просто ссылкой не судьба?) 

> <a href='http://example.com/search?page=N'>...

Answer (score 1):

По сути, это таже [постраничная навигация](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=постраничная+навигация+php). Разобравшись в её механизме, вы без труда реализуете (*звучит проще, чем имплементация, но к народу ближе*;) ) и свою задумку. А на чем будет она основана - решать только вам: или обычный GET-запрос, или с использованием ajax, etc.

Comment: Без обид. Не знал как эта штука называется. ; )